# Python how to know if a list has been modified

Tags: python, list, object

Sorry for the misleading title and newbie question. In the following code:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
idlst_init = id(lst)

lst.append(4)
del lst[lst.index(4)]

idlst_final = id(lst)

print(idlst_init == idlst_final)
# True
```

Is there any programmatic way (other than looking at the code) of assessing that some operations were carried out using the list `lst`. Using the `id()` built-in shows that it is the same object, but is it even possible to know the "history" of modifications of an object?

Comment: you could create own class to keep data and history. You could also add list for functions which have to be executed when you change value - in often is called `listener`

Comment: FYI, `del lst[lst.index(4)]` is equivalent to `lst.remove(4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own class by subclassing [collections.UserList](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList). An Example:

```
import collections

class myList(collections.UserList):
    def __init__(self, l=None):
        super().__init__(l or [])
        self.edits = []

    def append(self, el):
        super().append(el)
        self.edits.append(f"added {el}")

    def __delitem__(self, idx):
        super().__delitem__(idx)
        self.edits.append(f"removed element at index {idx}")
        
    def clear(self):
        super().clear()
        self.edits.append('cleared')

l = myList([1,2,3])
l.append(1)
del l[0]
l.clear()
print(l.__dict__) # {'data': [], 'edits': ['added 1', 'removed element at index 0', 'cleared']}
```

Answer (score 0):

No way to do it in pure python or with any module. You need to write  your own data structure spesific class to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No, list or any standard python object does not have such functionality.
*id(x)* returns a memory address of an object. List is a mutable object (as opposed to a tuple or a string) so by modifying it you do not create a new object, its memory address and therefore the result of *id()* does not change.
As **furas** already suggested, you should create your own object which can track its changes.